# JPopupMenu: Setting transparency/alpha foreground and background values

Tags: java, transparency, jcomponent, jpopupmenu

Is it possible to set the transperency values of a `JComponent`?

I want to set the *alpha* value of the foreground and background colors of a `JPopupMenu` dynamically.

```
 JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
 [...]
 popup.add(jpanel);
 popup.show(...);
 popup.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 20));
```

And after that:

```
 popup.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 40));
```

However, I can't see any transparency.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't edit so many of your old posts with trivial edit. It's bumping them all to the front page, and it trips moderator flags.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are really trying to do. The `setForeground()` method is only for setting text on the component. A popup menu doesn't display any text. You add JMenuItems to a popup menu. You can make the text of a menu item transparent:

```
JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("A popup menu item");
menuItem.setForeground( new Color(255, 0, 0, 50) );
popup.add( menuItem );
```

If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem because your question is not very clear.